# How to convert file read as binary string to Uint8Array not giving the same value as when using ArrayBuffer?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to read a file like *Binary String* and convert it to *UInt8Array* for processing (I use a library that uses this format for it's manipulation), however I use other libraries that use raw string data when they do processing. So I need to read data in one of the following ways:

- as *Binary String*
- as *Array Buffer*

and convert the data to the other type when passing it to the lib that is using the other data type. When I read the data as an *Array Buffer* and pass it's value to the library A it works perfectly. However if I read the data as a *Binary String* and try to convert it to *UInt8Array* like this:

```
const enc = new TextEncoder();
fileContent = enc.encode(fileContent);
```

the lib A isn't processing the data  properly.

When I take a look at the *UInt8Array* view that is created when I read the file directly as an *ArrayBuffer* I see that the length of it is 65385 bytes. However, when I read the file like *Binary String* and convert it like in the snippet above I get an *UInt8Array* of length 96074 bytes. So, I must be doing something wrong, but can't find exactly what. What is the right way to convert a *Binary String* to 
*ArrayBuffer*.

Comment: Why would you use **TextEncoder** for binary data? seems to make no sense to me - also, what is the correct length?

Comment: The correct length is 65385

Comment: So, clearly using a **Text**Encoder isn't the right strategy - so, you have an ArrayBuffer and you want a UInt8Array?

Comment: What do you call a "binary string" exactly? Remember that TextEncoder encodes to UTF-8.